# Is it possible to design an application that tells me how much time my child has used an app on his device.?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, parent, children

I am designing a kids learning and gaming application, and I want to have a parent application too for this. Is it possible that I can monitor for how much time my child has used the app, at what time of the day, turn the application off or on for the child, and also see his performance on different learning modules of app. ? Can someone give me idea of how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this would "technically" be possibly. However, I think your approach to this is flawed. For starters I would use StackOverflow for more technical based questions about specific issues you'll run into when building the app. As far as "can someone give me idea of how to accomplish it" you'll need to research and watch tutorials on building basic apps and work your way up. It's obvious you had an idea for an app and are passionate about pursuing it or else you wouldn't be asking this question on here. So my advice is to keep researching the basics of app development. Watch a tutorial on android studio and begin familiarizing yourself with app design. Best of luck.